# Play Framework 2.0 H2 browser port setting

Tags: playframework-2.0, h2

Does anyone know how to configure play framework H2 console's port?  I know the default is 8082, but unfortunately that port is already in use and I'm not sure how to change it to something else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that work in this case, but H2 stores the port of the console in the file `~/.h2.server.properties` (that is, the file named `.h2.server.properties` in the current user home directory). The contents of the file are the entries in the connection drop down list, plus a few options:

```
#H2 Server Properties
0=...
1=...
2=...
webAllowOthers=false
webPort=8082
webSSL=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible release the port 8082 for a while, open H2 console and change port in the options. After that stop the console and run again software that uses 8082, next time H2 will start on the port saved in Options.